# Record short Audio and Upload on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

Heh guys,
is it possible to record a small voice audio on the iPhone and upload it to a server?!
Any good sources on this topic? (Audio Recording).

Thanks,
Henrik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the code to record audio from

"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1"   which is provided by apple.

After recording audio, you can convert it to base64 and upload it to server by web service.

Cheers,
Pragnesh